# Internet in Ubuntu not working

Tags: ubuntu, internet, interface

I have an issue with the internet connection in Ubuntu not working any longer.

I have two NIC's. Both static. One with a internet IP and one local. I can SSH into local fine, but the internet IP cannot be seen outside the network. I have 5 static internet IP's (only 1 assigned to this server) and the others work fine with the same configurations, so I know it's not the ISP. I can also ping the other internet IPs I have, but I can't ping out - say to google's 8.8.8.8.

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
XX.49.84.232   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth1
172.24.98.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         XX.49.84.238   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1

/etc/network/interfaces file:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.24.98.60
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address XX.49.84.237
gateway XX.49.84.238
netmask 255.255.255.248
```

Any ideas?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check route to 8.8.8.8:

```
$ ip ro get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via XX.49.84.238 dev eth0  src XX.49.84.237 
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64
```

Then run tcpdump and ping 8.8.8.8:

```
# tcpdump -pni eth1                  (one console)
# ping 8.8.8.8                       (second console)
```

Copy output in question.

Also check ARP:

```
$ arp -a
XX.49.84.238 (XX.49.84.238) в xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx [ether] на eth1
```

And iptables rules:

```
# iptables -nv -L
```

Comment: ip ro get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via XX.49.84.238 dev eth1  src XX.49.84.237
    cache  mtu 1500 advmss 1460 hoplimit 64

Comment: Ok, then run tcpdump and ping simultaneity

Comment: tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:12:21.522105 IP XX.49.84.237 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 4868, seq 1, length 64

--- times 5


ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4033ms

Comment: arp -a does nothing

Comment: sudo iptables -nv -L
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: please add all output in qestion(use edit)... "tracepath -n 8.8.8.8" ?

Comment: "arping XX.49.84.238"?

Comment: (edit)  tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
 1:  XX.49.84.237                                         2.146ms pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
12:  no reply
13:  no reply
14:  no reply
15:  no reply
16:  no reply
17:  no reply
18:  no reply
19:  no reply
20:  no reply
21:  no reply
22:  no reply
23:  no reply
24:  no reply
25:  no reply
26:  no reply
27:  no reply
28:  no reply
29:  no reply
30:  no reply
31:  no reply
     Too many hops: pmtu 1500
     Resume: pmtu 1500

Comment: arp -a XX.49.84.238
? (XX.49.84.238) at 00:13:f7:9c:af:98 [ether] on eth1

Comment: try again "tcpdump -pni eth1" and "dig google.com @8.8.8.8"

Comment: `  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
    10:49:18.788840 ARP, Request who-has XX.49.84.238 tell XX.49.84.237, length 28
    10:49:18.789825 ARP, Reply XX.49.84.238 is-at 00:13:f7:9c:af:98, length 46
    10:49:18.789908 IP XX.49.84.237.40104 > 8.8.8.8.53: 61892+ A? google.com. (28)


    dig google.com @8.8.8.8
    
    ; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> google.com @8.8.8.8
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
`

Comment: try change address to other in the same network

Comment: Well...I changed the internet IP to another one in my range (XX.49.84.235) and everything works.  Is that a clue as to why this one could be not working?

Comment: most likely a problem with ISP

Comment: Ok.  Well thank you very much for your help today.

Comment: Instead of `arp -a`, you can use `ip neigh`.